# PXE Kickstart not happening

Tags: redhat

We are trying to do a PXE boot and we get the following errror :

==quote==

| Erros parsing Kickstart Config |

The following error was found while parsing your kickstart configuration :

The following error occured on line 32 of the kickstart file :

Specified nonexistent disk cciss/c0d0 in clearpart command

```
              Reboot
```

==unquote==

can anyone tell me whats happening and how to trouble shoot this issue .

Rgds
Nishant

---

Actually , I used the disk type before also , now we are adding LUN's in the setup ...adn somehow the disks are not being read I guess ...

Comment: What's on line 32 of the kickstart config file?

Comment: I can pretty much guarantee it's `clearpart /dev/cciss/c0d0`

Answer (score 1):

cciss/c0d0 is for HP's RAID controllers.  LUNs need to be mapped.  You want to point it at /dev/mapper (if you're using Multipath), et al.  You know your SAN configuration better than we do (how many LUNs, multipath or not, etc), and you did not provide that information.

Answer (score 1):

If you are indeed trying to install on an HP server using /dev/cciss/..., You'll need this line in your kickstart config:

device scsi cciss megaraid